# Google Analytics exclude internal traffic not working

Tags: google-analytics, ip, analytics, exclude-constraint

I try to [create a new filter](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034823) but it didn't work!
When I exclude my Ip Address. I can still view my tracing moves on page "Real-time".
I have a link with Google Tag Manager...

Should I set something else for exclude my Ip Address?

Comment: welcome to stack please read  [ask] edit your question and include [example]

Comment: show screen of your configuration and analytics tag, pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP exclusion filters in Google Analytics are notoriously faulty, and as another user said, can't catch scenarios in which dynamic IPs are in play.

The best workaround I've found for this is to install the [Block Yourself from Analytics](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/block-yourself-from-analy/fadgflmigmogfionelcpalhohefbnehm?hl=en) Chrome extension.  Seems to work great.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen either if you have a dynamic IP or because you are using the `anonymizeIp` which sets the last octet of the IP to 0, thus losing the correspondence between the IP and the value entered in the filter.